# question about laws of logical equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

i've this question which I have to **solve using laws of logical equivalence** but I can't. I've been trying to solve this since a few hours now.

**p ⊕ ( ¬ p ∧ q) ≡ p ∨ q**

I tried to solve the  LHS using  **a ⊕ b = (a V b) ∧ ¬ (a ∧ b)**
but can't complete the question as I keep getting stuck.
what i've tried so far on the LHS

**[p V (¬p ∧ q)] ∧ ¬[p ∧ (¬p ∧ q)]**  (using the expression above)

**[(p V ¬p) ∧ (p V q)] ∧ ¬[p ∧ (¬p ∧ q)]** (using [a V (b ∧ c)] ≡ [(a V b) ∧ (a V c)])

**[T ∧ (p V q)] ∧ ¬[p ∧ (¬p ∧ q)]** (using (a V ¬a) ≡ T)

**(p V q) ∧ ¬[p ∧ (¬p ∧ q)]** (using (T ∧ a) ≡ a)

I can't go further, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

You have started correctly unwinding [exclusive or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Equivalences,_elimination,_and_introduction) :

> $[p \lor (\lnot p \land q)] \land \lnot [p \land (\lnot p \land q)]$.

The RHS is simply $\text T$, because $(p \land \lnot p) \equiv \text F$.

Then, we have to consider that $\alpha \land \text T \equiv \alpha$; thus, the formula amounts to the LHS only.

And you have already simplified it to $(p \lor q)$.